# Append method doesn't work in StringBuilder

Tags: java, android, string, android-widget, stringbuilder

I'm trying to create a small calculator widget but I can not concatenate the input string using `StringBuilder`, because the widget at every click on the button only displays the string corresponding to the button clicked.

It seems that the append method in `StringBuilder` is not working. Could you give me some help?

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReceive(): " + action);
    if (ACTION_WIDGET_CONTROL.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            fnHandleCommand(context, intent, appWidgetId);
        }
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

private void fnHandleCommand(Context context, Intent intent, int appWidgetId) {
    int control_id = intent.getIntExtra(COMMAND, -1);

    switch (control_id) {
    case R.id.Button00:
        String zero = "0";
        sb.append(zero);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button01:
        String uno = "1";
        sb.append(uno);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button02:
        String due = "2";
        sb.append(due);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button03:
        String tre = "3";
        sb.append(tre);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button04:
        String quattro = "4";
        sb.append(quattro);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button05:
        String cinque = "5";
        sb.append(cinque);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button06:
        String sei = "6";
        sb.append(sei);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button07:
        String sette = "7";
        sb.append(sette);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button08:
        String otto = "8";
        sb.append(otto);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.Button09:
        String nove = "9";
        sb.append(nove);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonPlus:
        String piu = "+";
        sb.append(piu);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonMinus:
        String meno = "-";
        sb.append(meno);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonMutiple:
        String per = "*";
        sb.append(per);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonDivide:
        String diviso = "/";
        sb.append(diviso);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonNegative:
        String rad = "\u221a";
        sb.append(rad);
        setInputText(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonAC: 
        String vuota = "";
        sb.setLength(0);
        cancel(context, appWidgetId,sb.toString(),vuota);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    fnVibrate(context);
}

private void setInputText(Context context, int appWidgetId, String value) {
    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.simple_calculator);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.TextValue, value);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,
            remoteView);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging into it? The chances of `StringBuilder.append` not working are *much* smaller than the chances of it being a problem elsewhere... I suspect you'll find that some piece of code you haven't posted is clearing the `StringBuilder` between clicks. Log (or inspect with a debugger) the value of `sb` at the *start* of `fnHandleCommand`.

Comment: and what is the problem you have?

Comment: it seems that the stringbuilder is initialized at every click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private **static** StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();

Comment: So now the StringBuilder is shared between all instances of whatever the Java class was. That doesn't sounds like a particularly good idea. If the StringBuilder was really recreated every time (I would think it's much more likely that his command handler is not being called) he should take the current input text of the widget, append whatever he wants to to that text, and then set it again.

Comment: The thing is that input text if the widget is recreated too. Whole widget with all fields recreates everytime. Easiest solution is above. Another solution is to save text into preferences and everytime reload it from them.